# Killing form - strange definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I was just reading about [Killing forms.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing-Form) In my opinion, the definition of these forms is quite strange. I mean why would one define $B(X,Y) = \mathrm{tr} (\mathrm{ad} (X) \circ \mathrm{ad} (Y))$?  I would have expected $B(X,Y) = \mathrm{tr} (\mathrm{ad} (X)^* \circ \mathrm{ad} (Y)).$  At least for matrix groups, this seems to be a more intuitive definition, similar to the standard Frobenius inner product for matrices.

Comment: Killing form is not supposed to be a non-degenerate bilinear form. That is the case only when the Lie algebra is semi-simple.

Comment: Well, at first glance, you want $B([X,Y],Z)=B(X,[Y,Z])$, which does not seem to hold in "your" definition.

Answer (score 2):

"Why would one define $B(X,Y)=tr(ad(X)ad(Y))$ ?" You are right, for matrix algebras I would define a bilinear form more simply, namely just by $C(X,Y)=tr(X)tr(Y)$. This is very natural, because a trace form for linear operators is the easiest thing you can imagine. If we do not have linear operators $X,Y$, then we can enforce this, by using the adjoint representation of the Lie algebra. So it is very natural, to use the trace of $ad(X)$ and $ad(Y)$ (and it has many other advantages, as mentioned in the comments). 
Later it turns out that for simple Lie algebras, both forms are almost identical. They just differ by a non-zero constant, i.e. $B(X,Y)=\lambda C(X,Y)$.